# Submenu wrong position in Delphi application

Tags: delphi, menu, program-entry-point

My application is written in delphi. For some reason the main menu does not behave anymore like it did until yesterday (I probably touched some property without knowing). Now when I click on a menu item with sub-items, though the arrow is located to the right, the submenu keeps opening to the left.

[image]

What is the reason and how do I restore it back?

Comment: Popup the menu, so that the submenu will fit on the current desktop. Windows does this automatically, if the submenu would be out of desktop, it's displayed on the other side.

Comment: thanks but the submenu opens in the center of the desktop, it's not because of windows automatic behavior. I have been developing this app for years and this has never happened before.

Comment: Please edit to post an image that shows the problem (provide a link to an image we can see, and someone here can inline it for you). I've never seen this issue, and I've used Delphi extensively from v1 to XE2 (and am checking out XE3). Also, is it a `TMainMenu` or `TPopupMenu`?

Comment: Ok this is a link for the pic: http://nwscomps.com/ss_mainmenu.jpg
This is a main menu and I am using good old D5 on Windows 7 ultimate. This behavior began after installing a whole bunch of Win7 updates, could it be related?

Comment: Forgot to say this does not happen in design time but only at runtime!

Comment: How about menus of other applications?

Comment: Hello Sertac, good question! Actually I now opened Microsoft Expression web to try the menus there and guess what? SAME PROBLEM. What's going on with my Windows ??

Comment: Search for something like tablet pc settings in the control panel, or something related with touch screen, input devices etc.. Opening sub menus on the left makes them easier to see when for instance you're using a pen or the like with your right hand..

Comment: Sertac, thank you a lot! That fixed it. I changed the option in tablet pc settings. I have no idea why the evil-windows decided to change it. I usually never update the os it was a chance that yesterday I did that and see what happened...thanks

Comment: @Sertac: Nice catch! You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Ken, thanks. The question will be closed and deleted in no time (I also voted for close). But it might as well have an answer till it does..

Comment: @Sertac: I only see one vote to close - it must be yours. ;-) It turns out it wasn't programming-related but it didn't appear so at first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As revealed in the comments to the question, this is not programming related. There's a setting that does this in tablet pc settings in control panel. The reason for the setting is, when one is using a pen or the like with the right hand, sub menus, if opened to the right of their parent menu, are obscured by the pen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it had nothing to do with my "touch screen" or other pc tablet related settings
I found out by changing some features of the MainMenu of type TMainMenu:
Just set the "OwnerDraw" feature to False and "ParentBiDiMode" to true 
So if your parent view is already fine this MainMenu (submenu) will conform to its parent.
I did it 100s of times and it worked for me

Comment: I wonder why did you do that 100s of times since "ParentBiDiMode" is "true" and "OwnerDraw" is "false" by default already.

Comment: on 100 projects i meant

Comment: And I meant OwnerDraw is already false by default and ParentBiDiMode is already true by default, why have you changed them and then reverted back to their defaults on 100 projects?

Comment: I always had some problems on it 
on any project 
some times they turned all by they own